# pfSense: Local subdomain per Interface w/ DHCP

Tags: dhcp, subdomain, pfsense, internal-dns

I am running pfSense 2.3.2-RELEASE-p1 with multiple local interfaces, each with a DHCP service configured. The DNS Resolver service is configured to register DHCP leases and DHCP static mappings.

In System -> General Setup -> Domain, I have `admin.mydomain.eg` set, and for each of the DHCP Servers I have a separate domain name configured to represent the different networks. The idea being that I can have a host with interfaces on the different networks that I access with an FQDN.

- ADMIN - 192.168.10.0/34 (default `admin.mydomain.eg`)
- HOME - 192.168.20.0/24 (`home.mydomain.eg`)
- SERVICE - 192.168.30.0/24 (`service.mydomain.eg`)

The problem is that only the default domain seems to be the only one that registers DHCP leases. For example, I bring up the ADMIN interface on `host-01`, and I get a DHCP lease of `192.168.10.16` and a DNS entry for `host-01.admin.mydomin.eg`. Then I bring up the SERVICE interface and receive a DHCP lease of `192.168.30.54` but no DNS entry for `host-01.service.mydomain.eg`. A quick dig show that that `host-01.admin.mydomain.eg` is actually now pointing at `192.168.30.54`.

I think I must be missing some config in the DNS service to support multiple local domains, but I'm not sure what. Has anyone tried this with any success?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's due to a [5 year-old bug](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/1819) that is just getting some traction again.